# Proof By Induction Sigma Series

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question and have managed to get this far:[image]

The original question was:
[image]

I am at a loss at what to do next? I am guessing I need to factor it out so I get $3^{k+1}-1$ somewhere in the equation?

Comment: The induction is on $n$, and states that the each sum on the left can be rewritten as what stays on the right hand side. Thus my advice is to split the sum up to $n-1$ and then add the remaining term. Then use the induction step. As @timmbob did in his answer

Comment: A quick guide to formatting math on this website: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an equivalence of Principle of Induction, The Well-ordering principle.
Let be $X=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n}4\times3^r\neq6(3^n-1)\}$,
Suposse $X\neq\emptyset$ so for the Well-ordering principle, there exist some $k\in X$ the minimum element, so $k\neq 1$ thus $1\in X^c$ (you show this in your proccedure).
$$\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{k}4\times3^r\neq6(3^k-1)...(1)$$
Thus $k\neq1, \exists k-1\in\mathbb{N}$ such $s(k-1)=k$, $k-1<k$ so $k-1\in X^c$, because $k$ is the minimun of $X$:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}4\times3^r=6(3^{k-1}-1)...(2)$$

In $(2)$, sum to both sides $4\times3^k$ and with some aritmetic you must show and contradiction that holds to suppose $X\neq\emptyset$, then $X=\emptyset$ and it holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}4\cdot 3^r=\underbrace{\sum_{r=1}^n 4\cdot 3^r}_{=6(3^n-1)\ by\ hypothesis}+4\cdot 3^{n+1}=6(3^n-1)+4\cdot 3^{n+1}$$$$\underset{(*)}{=}2\cdot 3^{n+1}-6+4\cdot 3^{n+1}=6\cdot 3^{n+1}-6=6(3^{n+1}-1),$$

what conclude the proof.

For $(*)$, notice that $$6\cdot 3^n=2\cdot 3\cdot 3^n=2\cdot 3^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks man, that makes sense, I didn't notice what you stared!