# How to prove that the recurrence $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n^2a_{n-2}$ gives $(n+1)!$ without induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> Define the sequence $\{a_n\}$ by $a_{1}=2,a_{2}=6$, and for $n>2$, 
>   $$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n^2a_{n-2}$$

show that
$$a_{n}=(n+1)!$$

I know if we use induction,it is easy to prove it.
$$n!+n^2(n-1)!=n![1+n]=(n+1)!$$

But without using induction, can we prove this result?

Comment: did you tried with the well-ordered principle? Here is an example
 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225561/proof-by-induction-sigma-series/1225579#1225579

Comment: There's a question you might want to ask.. which is that sometimes people who create such problems start from the desired function and then obtain the recurrence...

Comment: @Luis: That *is* induction. There is no essential difference.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, just asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide
$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+n^2 a_{n-2}
$$
by $a_{n-1}$:
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=1+n^2\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_{n-1}}
$$
Let $x_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$; so,
$$
x_n=1+\frac{n^2}{x_{n-1}}.
$$
$x_n=n+1$ is a solution of it:
$$
n+1=1+\frac{n^2}{(n-1)+1}.
$$
So, $a_n/a_{n-1}=n+1$ and $a_n=C(n+1)!$. $a_1=2\Longrightarrow C=1$.

Comment: Technically, your proof still uses induction (in the last sentence). For sequences definde by recursion, proofs using induction are essentially unavoidable. (Also, just noting that $x_n=n+1$ is a solution does not show that it's the only solution. Otherwise, why not just insert $a_n=(n+1)!$ to begin with?)

Comment: @GregMartin, yes, I agreed that we implicitly used unduction. But I can define factorial by $fact(n)/fact(n-1)=n$ and $f(0)=1$. Since recurrence for $x_n$ has first order, there must be one solution. Anyway, questions like "prove whatever that obviously prooved by induction without induction" are not very interesting; proof will be use some tricks (like $a_n = (obvious\_soltion)b_n$)

Comment: I agree, Michael! - probably my comment is more aimed at the problem statement itself than your solution.

Comment: @GregMartin I think, it's dispute about factorial: factorial is recursive or iterative "by it's nature")

Answer (score 2):

Well, if we *know* that
the solution to
$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n^2a_{n-2}
$
is
$a_n
=(n+1)!
$,
let's let
$a_n
=(n+1)!b_n
$
(with initial values
$b_1 = b_2 = 1$
and see what happens.

$(n+1)!b_n
=n!b_{n-1}+n^2(n-1)!b_{n-2}
=n!b_{n-1}+nn!b_{n-2}
$
or
$(n+1)b_n
=b_{n-1}+nb_{n-2}
$.

And for this,
we see that
$b_n = 1$
is the solution.

Note that from
$(n+1)b_n
=b_{n-1}+nb_{n-2}
$,
$(n+1)b_n-(n+1)b_{n-1}
=-nb_{n-1}+nb_{n-2}
$
or
$(n+1)(b_n-b_{n-1})
=-n(b_{n-1}-b_{n-2})
$.
Since
$b_1 = b_2 = 1$,
this implies that
$b_n = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I typed the same solution just seconds faster. If two or more have the same process then it must be right.

Comment: Great minds think alike. Although I don't see why you used $\Gamma$.

Comment: just a preference of notation

Comment: Technically, your proof still uses induction (in the last sentence). For sequences definde by recursion, proofs using induction are essentially unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $a_{1}=2,a_{2}=6$, $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n^2a_{n-2}$. Let $a_{n} = \Gamma(n+2) \, b_{n}$ for which it is seen that:
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+2) \, b_{n} = \Gamma(n+1) \, b_{n-1} + n \, \Gamma(n+1) \, b_{n} 
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
(n+1) \, b_{n} = b_{n-1} + n \, b_{n-2}
\end{align}
where $b_{1} = b_{2} = 1$. By calculating the next set of terms it is quickly realized that $b_{n} = 1$ for $n \geq 1$. Utilizing this result it is determined that the solution to $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n^2a_{n-2}$ is $a_{n} = \Gamma(n+2)$.

Comment: Technically, your proof still uses induction (in the second-to-last sentence). For sequences definde by recursion, proofs using induction are essentially unavoidable.